# Excel: Fake Blank Cell (cell has no content, nothing in the function box, but not recognized as a blank cell)

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, cell-format

I have an Excel file with plenty of "blank" cells, these cells are not showing any content in the cell itself nor in the function box. And I'm trying to replace all these "blank" cells with a specific value.

However, when I was trying to do so (using "Go to special - bank cells"), I was not able to do so. Because these cells are not recognized as blank. I've used "ISBLANK" function to check, and the results are "FALSE", which means the cells are indeed not blank.

I'm 100% sure that the I cannot see any content in the cell itself nor in the function box (not even a space). I can make the cell blank by click on it and press the "delete" key on my keyboard (nothing will change visibly). But this is too time-consuming since there are plenty of them.

I'm wondering is there a convenient way to change all these "fake blank" cells to a specific value?

Comment: could there be a space or other non printable character in it?

Comment: try press ctrl+H replace all spaces (make sure you use exact match) with nothing

Comment: Select cell(s), Ribbon Menu, Data section, (portion far to the right) -> Clear All Data

Comment: There's definitely no space, maybe non printable characters, but I cannot tell. The good news is that I've found out an easy way to do it, just copy the cell and paste it to the replace box. No matter what is contained, excel will recognize.

Comment: probably a `Tab` then, which Excel ignores but the cell will contain.

Comment: Could you provide a sample file about you said blank cell?